# Parsing repeated matches from a ruby string?

Tags: ruby, regex, string, parsing

Maybe I'm just pretty tired, but I don't see an obvious way to parse out the numbers from a string like this:

```
some text here, and then 725.010, 725.045, 725.340 and 725.370; and more text
```

One thing that occurred to me: split this by spaces into an array. Then apply a regex test with a group to each element in the array.

Is there a cleaner, simpler way to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, everyone. I had forgotten about String#scan. These are statute numbers, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [String#scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M000812):

```
your_string.scan(/\d\d\d\.\d\d\d/)
```

will output array of matches.

Answer (score 5):

```
result = subject.scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)
```

This will find integers or decimals in a string and put them (still as strings, though) into the array `result`.

Comment: To get them as floats, just do `result = subject.scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f)`.